# Override and add new class member in c#

Tags: c#, overriding

How to do something like this (without creating intermediate classes):

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract string Text { get; }
}

class B : A
{
    string text = "";
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
    }

    new public string Text
    {
        get { return (this as A).Text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}
```

Compiler say: The type 'B' already contains a definition for 'Text'.

Clarification: How to do so(but without class "Intermediate"):

```
abstract class A
{
    public abstract string Text { get; }
}

class Intermediate : A
{

    protected string text = "";

    public override string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
    }

}

class B : Intermediate
{
    new public string Text
    {
        get { return (this as A).Text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do want to do this?

Comment: I want readonly property in A(and subclasses) and read/write property in B(and subclasses)

Answer (score 4):

If you want the property to be read-write in derived class, then it is impossible.
The property is a syntax sugar for `PropertyType get_PropertyName()` (when the property is readable) and `void set_PropertyName(PropertyType value)` (when the property is writable) methods. This line:

```
public abstract string Text { get; }
```

means:

```
public abstract string get_Text();
```

And this:

```
public override string Text{ get; set;}
```

means:

```
public override string get_Text()
{
   // ...
}

public override void set_Text(string value)
{
   // ...
}
```

Since there's no abstract `set_Text` method in base class, you can't override it.

Comment: I understand. Another question - how to do override and add new member with same name (hide first) in one class. It possible in two classes

Comment: @Michael: can you modify `A`?

Comment: Yes, you can modify A, but would like that A.Text was is abstract

Comment: @Michael: then make it `public abstract string Text { get; set; }`. The property still will be abstract, but it also will be writable.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the property Text twice in the same class. You are overriding it and using the keyword new. Delete the second copy of Text.

```
class B : A
{
    private string text;
    public override string Text{ get; set;}      

}
```

Comment: Compiller say: cannot override because 'A.Text' does not have an overridable set accessor

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of do this with an interface:

```
interface A
{
    // The interface requires that Text is *at least* read only
    string Text { get; }
}

class B : A
{
    string text = "";

    // Implement Text as read-write
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { text = value; }
    }
}
```

If that's not going to work for you, you can simply add a `TextEx` property that is read-write:

```
public string TextEx
{
    get { return text; }
    set { text = value;
}

public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
}
```